# Objective-C: Adding UIButtons programmatically from another class

Tags: objective-c, class, uibutton

I'm having trouble connecting the dots between code and .xib files.

If I want to add a series of `UIButtons` programmatically to my view controller, how would I go about doing this from a separate class?

For instance, if I have `MainViewController.m`, which is set as the root view controller in Xcode, how can I add a `UIButton` to that view controller from `SecondViewController.m`? Is this even possible?

I would essentially like to place all of my "user interface" code in a separate class.

Thanks

Comment: Why?  You have your view in the XIB, the controller and hopefully a separate model.  Why have controllers and views that poke at each other?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, create a `UIButton *myButton` programmatically and then call `[mainViewController addSubview:myButton];`. This may mean you need to store a `MainViewController *` property in your `SecondViewController` class.

Important methods and properties for a [`UIButton`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) instance (essentially, just take a look at the documentation, but here's a minimal set of stuff to get you started):

- `+[UIButton buttonWithType:buttonType]` - Make sure if you're doing anything remotely custom to use `UIButtonTypeCustom` here (it doesn't give you any default background images or otherwise to have to `nil` out)
- `setFrame:` - Position the button relative to its container and set the size, for usability reasons the `width` and `height` should be at least `44` pixels (as mentioned [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Characteristics/Characteristics.html)).
- `setTitle:forState:` - `UIControlStateNormal` will act as the default properties for other states too, so you may only need to set the text here
- `setBackgroundImage:forState:` - use `UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControlStateHighlighted`/`UIControlStateSelected` primarily, `UIControlStateDisabled` if you wish to show it grayed out or inaccessible at any point.
- `setImage:forState:` - Use for an icon next to the button text (like an arrow pointing down for Save or up for Load, etc)
- `setEnabled:`, `setHidden:`, `setSelected:` - Transition between different button states. `setHighlighted:` happens automatically when you tap the button.
- `addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside` - TouchUpInside is almost always what you want for a simple button press, I'm using a method named `buttonClicked:` here to handle my button press.

Oh, and if you use `[[UIButton alloc] initWith...]` don't forget to `[myButton release]` once it's added to the `mainViewController` :)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 #import "MainViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController
{
  MainViewController *mainView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)  MainViewController *mainView;

-(void)addButtons;
```

In your implementation

```
@synthesize mainView;

-(void)addButtons
{
  UIButton *add = [UIButton alloc] init];
//do necessary stuff on button here
[self.mainView addSubview:add];
[add release];
}
```

In your MainViewcontroller.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[self superViewDidLoad];
SecondViewController *second = [SecondViewController alloc] init];
second.mainView = self;
[second addButton];
[second release];
}
```